# MooTools: Fx.slide couldn't get it worked

Tags: mootools

i am pretty new to mootools, i found it faster/smoother for animations than jquery so i decided to give it a try.

I don't get why the following code is not working, it is working on jsfiddle with Mootools core and Mootools more 1.3.1

```
<html>
<head>


<script src="mootools-more-1.3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="mootools-core-1.3.1-full-compat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    var myVerticalSlide = new Fx.Slide('paragraph', {mode:'horizontal'}) ;


    $('v_slideout').addEvent('click', function(event){
        event.stop();
        myVerticalSlide.toggle();
    });



});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="paragraph">This is a paragraph.</div>
<a id="v_slideout" href="#">Test</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Can't seem to figure it out, i only could get it worked on jsfiddle.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/F54s3/ << It doesn't work as it should in FF but still it does something, on Opera it seems fine though.
I might have messed up the code as i am pretty new to it, but i am trying to figure out why it works on jsfiddle and doesn't work on my index.html.

Comment: You should probably include the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your script includes looks suspicious to me:

```
<script src="mootools-more-1.3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="mootools-core-1.3.1-full-compat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Shouldn't the mootools-core file come first?

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AxJq9/ (throws Javascript error)

```
<script src="http://mootools.net/assets/scripts/mootools.more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.1/mootools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AxJq9/1/ (doesn't throw an error)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.1/mootools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://mootools.net/assets/scripts/mootools.more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thank you, i didn't think it would cause the problem.

Comment: @Tumay - No problem. Please vote up and click the checkmark next to my question. :)